# include inside a method: a fix for limited scope?

Tags: php

I'm building a small wrapper for some phpBB code (these methods will be invoked from various section of project).

The problem is: due to http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php , everything I include inside my wrapper has that-method-only scope.

Here the simplified and relevant part:

```
public function usePhpBBUsers($phpbb_root_path)
    {
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.php');
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.php');

    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup();
    }
```

I can workaround the variables scope with `global`, but those includes import function definition, too.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the keyword `global` ?

Comment: @Ibu Have you read the question?

Answer (score 1):

Function definitions will be **always** global. .........

Comment: @Mchl if they are namespaced they are global as well. Namespacing has nothing to do with scopes

Comment: I would say 'yes and no' to this. True: it has nothing to do with variable scope as described in manual page linked above. Namespaced functions will however take precedence over nonnamespaced functions within the namespace they're declared in or imported into.

Comment: @Mchl That's still irrelevant. You can explicitly call either function from anywhere. Namespacing is only about the *name* by which to call a function, nothing more.

Comment: @Mchl That's true but a little bit off-topic in this discussion as it has nothing to do with the include inside a function. If the fully qualified name is used, all functions can be accessed in a global scope

Comment: I can confirm due to first-hand tiries right now :) that the scope of function is limited to its namespace. In the example give in my question, a `group_memberships()` is defined: since the code I shown is inside a custom namespace, `mySpace\group_memberships()` works, just the function mane doesn't.

Comment: @deceze off-topic: this 3v4l.org website is a killer app!! :) nice

Comment: @DrG Of course, due to *name resolution*. The function is `foo\bar()`, not `bar()`. You can call it just fine from anywhere explicitly using `\foo\bar()`. The function is ***not*** in any form of limited *scope*.

Comment: Ok so we agree on it all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that functions definitions always have a global-scope http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

So the problem is down to variables-only: if I just declare every variabile in my inclues as `global` before the include, that should do the trick. Is a bit of inconvenience and this remove some loved abstratcion, but I think it's the only way.

Comment: You should not be mixing function declarations and variables. Put your functions in a separate file you can include without worrying about scope and create your variables elsewhere where they're needed.

Comment: That's out of my control: the file i'm including are from a different project, out of my control (are phpBB's).